# JDBC not working for logstash and mongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, elk, logstash-jdbc

[image: This is the Logstash Configuration file]

This Configuration gives the output as [unable to connect to the database and no suitable driver found!], i am using logstash version 7.5.1

Comment: Try the latest version JDBC

Comment: where can i find it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SOlved solution [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mongodb-logstash-integration-solved/122299) for the below code. Please ref the [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mongodb-logstash-integration-solved/122299) for more details

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "mongojdbc1.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://DB_ADDRESS:27017/DB_NAME"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_user => ""
        clean_run => false
        record_last_run => true
        last_run_metadata_path => "/path/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
        schedule => "*/10 * * * * *"
        jdbc_default_timezone => "YOUR_TIMEZONE"
        statement =>
        "
                    //well, actually this is JavaScript code. And was written in pure blood :(
                    var lastValue = :sql_last_value; //the last saved  date  that was scheduled to run query for
                    var HALF_HOUR_OFFSET = 1800000;

                    var extractedDate = lastValue.substring(0,10); //parsing the date of the last saved date
                    var year = Number(extractedDate.substring(0,4));
                    var month = Number(extractedDate.substring(5,7));
                    var day = Number(extractedDate.substring(8,10));

                    var extractedTime = lastValue.substring(11,23); //parsing the time of the last saved date
                    var hour = Number(extractedTime.substring(0,2));
                    var minute = Number(extractedTime.substring(3,5));
                    var seconds = Number(extractedTime.substring(6,8));
                    var miliseconds = Number(extractedTime.substring(9,12));

                    var upperEpoch = new Date(year,month-1,day,hour,minute,seconds,miliseconds).getTime(); //dates start from 0, that's why the minus 1
                    var bottomEpoch = upperEpoch - HALF_HOUR_OFFSET;

                    db.DB_COLLECTION.find({ COLLECTION_FIELD: { $gte : bottomEpoch, $lte: upperEpoch} },{'_id': false}); //we omit the 'id' since it irrelevant and also cause deserialize exception
                "
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share a link for mongojdbc1.2.jar file to download?

Comment: Yes. Sure.  http://www.unityjdbc.com/download.php?type=mongodb

Comment: @SanTiaGoKarThiCk Did you download ?

Comment: yes i did now i have a unityjdbc.jar in my unity installed folder , can  i have to use that jar file

Comment: @SanTiaGoKarThiCk Use the recently downloaded one.

Comment: yes after download i can seen unityjdbc.jar and mongodb_unity.jar which one i have to use and its a third party jar file. There is any option to use mongojdbc1.2.jar without third party like unity and progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207729/discussion-between-santiago-karthick-and-hariharan-ar).

Comment: what about the issue? did you fix it?

Comment: no still i am getting a same error as no suitable driver was found but it is working in ubuntu perfectly using mongojdbc1.6.jar not wokring in windows